# Import multiple-pages from a PDF as separate slides in Keynote

Tags: pdf, keynote

I have a PDF with slides in it from someone else and I want to import all the separate pages of the PDF as separate slides in Keynote. The best answer I can find is [this one on apple support](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1229204?start=0&tstart=0), but it suggests splitting the PDF into separate 1-page files to drag them into Keynote individually and I'm sure there must be an easier way.

Answer (score 13):

There’s a simple app called **PDF to Keynote** that does just this. From the developer’s description:

> PDF to Keynote converts PDF-based presentations (e.g., made using LaTeX and Prosper) into Apple's Keynote format.

I use it all the time for handling Beamer presentations, and it’s great. [Free to download](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/21623/pdf-to-keynote).

PS: This app does not suport current (November 2014) Keynote 6.5 file format.

Comment: It works though it seems to to at first sight.

Answer (score 10):

After experimenting a bit I found a pretty good way to do this - not fully automated but fairly simple and does the job. If you open the PDF in preview and enable the thumbnail mode, you can drag the individual page thumbnails across to Keynote slide panel and it will add that page as a slide.

Comment: This is good, but it's a shame you can't do this with multiple slides at a time

Comment: I also found this useful, but for some reason Keynote insisted on shrinking the slide quite a bit when I pasted it. So I had to manually edit each slide back to its original size. A pain, but workable.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Automator.app`, you can create a task that will generate pictures from pdf files (you can even do it with multiple files), just search for `Render PDF Pages to Images` action in automator. Once you run the action, you drag-n-drop generated pictures on the slides panel in `KeyNote` and you're done.

See [here for detailed instructions](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23322709#23322802)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the methods suggested in the other answers and was not successful.  I have Acrobat Pro so I just saved the PDF as JPEG, then put a JPEG onto each page of the Keynote presentation.  I'm sure there are better ways, but this worked easily for me.

Comment: What part of the other methods did not work for you? If you could comment on the answer containing the method the user could clarify the process such that it works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I used below converter, works good...

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pdf-converter-free/id422540367?mt=12&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

It's not mentioned specifically in the description of the app, but the comments in the reviews indicate it will convert a PDF to a Keynote presentation, not just a PowerPoint presentation.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple: open the PDF in Preview, make sure the thumbnails sidebar is visible. All the pages of the PDF will be shown on the left side of the window. Simply move Preview a little out of the way so you can see you Keynote presentation behind, highlight the page you want from the PDF thumbnails, drag and drop. Repeat this for all individual pages you require. I use this simple method to create a clickable document inside a single keynote slide.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above approaches worked for me, maybe because of updates in the 2+ years since the last reply. I am now on Mojave. Dragging a group of PDF page thumbnails from Preview adds a new slide to Keynote with one of the pages added as an image. This is the same result as individually dragging that one PDF page.

The following approach which copies one page at a time worked for me.

1. Add a new slide to Keynote and set its format to Photo. [image: Slide Format set to Photo in Keynote].
2. Switch (`CMD+TAB`) to Preview, select the PDF page thumbnail in Preview and copy (`CMD+C`) it.
3. Switch (`CMD+TAB`) to Keynote, click on the picture in the newly added slide.
4. Paste (`CMD+V`) the copied PDF page. It will replace the image in the slide, appropriately scaled to fit the entire slide.
5. If there are more PDF pages to copy, duplicate the slide you just pasted to, and repeat from 2.